# How to trigger a function with next or prev arrow clicks in tab-header-pagination? I want to load next or previous 3 tabs on every arrow click

Tags: angular, pagination, tabs, header, angular-material

https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#automatic-scroll-buttons 
I want a function like this using angular material mat-tab-header.

Answer (score 1):

In `Angular Material` this functionality is implemented in an automatic way. If you add more tabs, and your `window width` is too little, the buttons will appear.[See my example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxykdg?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: I know that, but my question is "Is it possible to change or control the behaviour of mat-tab-header-pagination click ?"  If it's possible then please tell me how to do that.